# How to go 2 views back in navigation based application

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a View based based application of 4 views. By using navigation controller I am changing the view. In my 3rd view one button is there. If I click on that button the app should come to the first view (2 views back).

I have used

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This is not working. It's going to the previous page only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this, and make change according your specification

```
-(void)goToMainCategoryView;
{
id object = nil;

for (UIViewController *viewControl in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if(viewControl.view.tag == 0)
    {
        object = viewControl;
    }
}
[self.navigationController popToViewController:object animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @umakanta:If my answer is helping you then accept or upvote my anwer

Answer (score 12):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[NeededViewController class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How sweet. Works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Another easy root to select the UIViewController by index would be to use:

```
NSArray *viewsArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *chosenView = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:chosenView animated:YES];
```

`chosenView` would then be the second view in the navigation stack (position 1). If you had a large stack and wanted to go a specific view.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

to go all the way back to the top view controller:

Documentation:

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
popToViewController:animated:
```

to go back to a particular view controller, supply the view controller you want to go to.

Documentation:

Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Parameters

viewController
The view controller that you want to be at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing in swift 1.2 :: xcode:6.4

```
for controller: UIViewController in self.navigationController?.viewControllers as! [UIViewController] {
        if controller.isKindOfClass(YourViewController) {
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
```